# PHP Log in System will not echo error statement

Tags: php

Hi i have just created a login system using php and mysql the login system works when entering a vaild username and password from the database but when i enter an invalid username and password it just loops back to the login page even though i have statment saying it fails that i want printed if the login fails here is my code file

```
<?php
require_once("Connections/connection.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 

$userid =   $_POST['userid'];
$password =  $_POST['password'];
$submitted =  $_POST['submitted'];
if ($userid && $password){
    $query  =sprintf("SELECT * FROM users where user_name= '$userid' and user_password = '$password'");
    $result =@mysql_query($query);
    $rowAccount =@mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
if ($rowAccount){
    echo "The record exists so you can enter ";

} elseif($submitted){
    print "you don't exist in the system!";
}


?>
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"> 
  <table width="800">
    <tr>
      <th width="233" scope="col">User ID </th>
      <th width="555" scope="col"><p>
        <label for="userid"></label>
        <label for="userid"></label>
        <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" />
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp; </p></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password </td>
      <td> <label for="userid"></label>       <label for="password"></label>

      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>   <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" />        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

to get the echo working  had to add a value to the hidden field and it worked

Comment: Your `elseif` statement only checks the value of `$_POST['submitted']`, not if there are any records...

Comment: does your hidden field "submitted" hold any sort of value?

Comment: Both the HTML and PHP code are in the same file? If yes then the message might be printing but you might only see it using view source option of your browser. Trying using die() after the message...

Comment: __error reporting ON with__ _@_ error suppressor. what a combination!

Comment: had error reports all over the place even though it worked so had to add that.but add the value to the hidden field seemed to solve that problem as well so i have taken it out

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

`elseif($submitted){
    print "you don't exist in the system!";
}`

to simply:

`else(){
    print "you don't exist in the system!";
}`

and see if you see your message then?

You are checking on a a variable that has no value and it is therefore returning as false and not firing your elseif statement.

Alternatively, you could change your HTML part to something like:

`<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="test" />`

You can see I have given it a test value for now just so that it returns true so as to fire your elseif statement.

Comment: i had to change my html text to  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="test"   the else(){print} didn't work   Thankyou for your help